# Elasticsearch - scroll timeout / keep alive

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ES 7.17 [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/scroll-api.html) feature to implement an infinite scrolling fetch on UI side.

Everything is working fine, except for an use case where users take too much time to request another chunk of data and the scroll timeouts.

I could increase the scroll timeout value to avoid that, but at same time I don't want to keep it alive for long periods of time without need for obvious memory consumption reasons.

I'm wondering if there is a way to send a sort of keep alive request to an specific scrollId without fetching the data, so my UI could be smart enough to identify that users are still working on that and send this request to make the scroll available longer without user interaction.

Any ideas on how to handle it using scroll or any other approach will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have update / delete? (=> does your data change and if any, theses modifications should be hide to the user while he is scrolling ?)

Comment: Let's say data never change in this case

Comment: In this case i would use, from size, keeping the from value in UI session.

Comment: used of FROM is not allowed in a scroll context

Comment: Yes, i wont use scroll here (because of the timeout snapshot issue you describe), i would used standard query with from, size. If your data never change, it wont be an issue.

Comment: got it, but I really want to use scroll since it is not that costly as from/size approach.

Comment: Create a snapshot is coslty on es side. Maybe you could use a simple int sequence field in your es documents in order to get easy scoring (but i imagine, it s wont be so easy ;))